# Selector de casos en un join en función de una condición, SQL

Tags: sql, mysqli

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy realizando una consulta a dos tablas que se encuentran unidas por un campo "id". La primera tabla incluye información estática en el tiempo, llamemosla tabla1. La segunda tabla (tabla2) para un mismo "id" tiene varios registros en función de un campo de estado, que dice si el resultado es una previsión o si por el contrario está confirmado (sólo existen esas dos posibilidades). Al ser un join con múltiples registros en la tabla destino me devuelve  duplicada la información de la tabla1. 
Me gustaría poner un selector que me hiciera el join con el registro 'confirmado' si existe y si no con el otro registro 'previsión' en función de una condición sobre ese campo. El esbozo que he hecho para sacar sólo los confirmados sería el siguiente:

```
SELECT (información requerida) FROM tabla1 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM tabla2 WHERE tabla2.estatus='confirmado') as 
tb2 
ON tabla1.id= tb2.id
```

Teniendo en cuenta que cualquier registro que esté en estado 'confirmado', automáticamente tiene su homólogo en estado 'previsión', que puede tener algún campo cambiado, o no. Y con eso es con lo que ya me pierdo ya que si hago un doble join, siempre me voy a encontrar con registros duplicados ya que los que me devuelve el join de 'confirmado', también me los devolvería un segundo join de 'previsión'.

```
SELECT (información requerida) FROM tabla1 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM tabla2 WHERE tabla2.estatus='confirmado') as 
tb2 
ON tabla1.id= tb2.id
JOIN (SELECT * FROM tabla2 WHERE tabla2.estatus='previsión') as 
tb3 
ON tabla1.id= tb3.id
```

No puedo modificar ninguno de los registros de la tabla, tengo que trabajar con la info tal y cómo está en origen.

Edit:

incluyo información de las tablas, el punto de unión es el campo 'position'

La primera (paso la tabla filtrada ya que tiene muchos más campos) tiene info general de la 'position'

[image: tabla1]

la segunda (cuyo campo key he borrado junto a otros para dejarlo más limpios) recoge la previsión inicial antes de la entrega y la realidad de la cantidad de energía suministrada.

[image: tabla2]

Quiero sacar la primera tabla junto con los campos el campo 'energy' y 'energyunit' en los casos que la entrega esté cerrada ('Trade') y en caso que no exista ese estado coger la previsión ('Forecast')

Comment: ¿No has pensado que quizá debes replantearte el diseño de tu modelo de datos? ¿A qué se debe que haya esa mezcla en una misma tabla? ¿No sería mejor empezar a hacer uso de una tabla asociativa para expresar ciertas relaciones? Si pones un ejemplo concreto de los datos quizá se puede tener una mejor idea para ayudarte en este caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano, es un modelo de datos que no he diseñado yo, es una herramienta estándar de mercado por lo que para mi es completamente inflexible. Te he adjuntado dos capturas de las tablas con tres contratos a modo ejemplo. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: La expresión *para mi es completamente inflexible*  quiere decir, en lenguaje llano, que no puedes modificar el modelo de datos, ¿cierto? Es importante saberlo, para tratar de resolverlo con lo que hay.

Comment: @A.Cedano exacto, yo sólo puedo sacar información del modelo de datos. No puedo ni insertar, ni crear ni nada. Sólo sacar información.

Comment: A ver si logramos entender mejor el asunto, porque la explicación me parece algo complicada. Tomemos el registro con `position` igual a `119400`. Dices que necesitas los datos en caso de que sea `FORECAST` y si no existe coincidencia, necesitas que busce entonces a `TRADE`. Pero en el ejemplo que muestras se dan las dos condiciones. ¿Qué debería pasar ahí, tomar en preferencia `FORECAST` e ignorar `TRADE` o tomar ambas filas? Veo también que hay a veces dos filas, una con `TRADE` y otra con `FORECAST`, pero ¿pueden haber más filas con el mismo `119400`. ¿Qué se requeriría en ese caso?

Comment: En el caso de la tabla1, el registro 'position' es único. En el caso de la tabla2 el registro 'position' puede no serlo pero cómo mucho va a tener dos registros o con valor 'forecast' o con valor 'trade'. Quiero para un id 119400, que me traiga el valor que tiene el estado 'trade', en caso de que no existiera ese valor que para ese mismo id me traiga 'forecast'. Te modifico la captura de la tabla2 para que haya dos 'position' sin estado 'Trade' sólo 'Forecast'.

Comment: @A.Cedano, sobre esta nueva foto lo que necesito es que para 119400 me traiga el valor 3579, ara el 119399 me traiga 1000, para 119398 me traiga 1500 (el que está en estado 'Trade' y que es diferente a forecast) y en el caso 119397 me traiga 1000 (que en este caso daría igual porque es lo mismo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu planteamiento de la segunda query está bien encaminado.

Si, como lo das a entender, todo registro de la tabla1 tiene *al menos* un forecast asociado, entonces al hacer

```
SELECT (información requerida) FROM tabla1 
LEFT JOIN tabla2 trades ON tabla1.id= trades.id AND trades.quantitystatus='TRADE'
LEFT JOIN tabla2 forecasts ON tabla1.id= forecasts.id AND forecasts.quantitystatus='FORECAST'
```

tendrás el valor de los `trades` cuando exista y NULL en caso contrario, y además el valor de los `forecasts` para toda la `tabla1`. En ese caso reeplaza los trades con valor NULL por lo obtenido de `forecasts`, que ocuparás sólo como fallback

```
SELECT tabla1.*,
       IFNULL(trades.quantitystatus,forecasts.quantitystatus),
       IFNULL(trades.energy, forecasts.energy),
       IFNULL(trades.energyunits, forecasts.energyunits)
FROM tabla1 
LEFT JOIN tabla2 trades ON tabla1.id= trades.id AND trades.quantitystatus='TRADE'
LEFT JOIN tabla2 forecasts ON tabla1.id= forecasts.id AND forecasts.quantitystatus='FORECAST'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amenadiel!